# same json_decode(), different result

Tags: php, json

I have following code

```
$geocode = file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='. 'new york' .'&sensor=false');

$output= json_decode($geocode);

echo $output;
```

I have this code in two different php-files.

In one it is working fine. in the other page $geocode gets filled but the json_decode command doesn't deliver a result. value of $geocode is exactly the same.

I tried `json_last_error()`, but it shows `error code 0`, so no error.

I can't understand it! What can be wrong?

Comment: Why are you using echo on an object. Use print_r or var_dump instead

Comment: if you output `$geocode` on the server that does not deliver the expected result (BEFORE using `json_decode()` on it), what is the contents of `$geocode`? Try: `var_dump( $geocode );`

Comment: value of geocode is in both files correct and 100% ident.  this echo command was only temporarly for debugging.  regular line then is $geoLocation = $output->results[0]->geometry->location;   has var_dump the same function as json_decode()?

Comment: Strange. The only reason I could think about is encoding issues (when the incoming data is not UTF-8) but I can't see how it could be an issue here.

Comment: same lines of code are working on another place and i tried it both hard coded too, so with all the same parameters

Comment: is it possible your get_file_contents response is empty? does a curl exhibit similar behavior?

Comment: get_file_contents response delivers a result